# Python3 insertion sort iterating backwards not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, insertion-sort

I'm a beginner in Python and am trying to implement insertion sort in the language. However, when I try my code on a list to sort I get the same list back. I figured out that the code isn't even going to the second loop. I am using Python 3. What is wrong with iterating backwards this way?

```
def ins_sort(us_in):
  tmp = None
  for key in range(1, len(us_in)-1):
    for i in range(key, 0, -1):
      if us_in[key] < us_in[i] and key != 0:
        tmp = us_in[key]
        us_in[key] = us_in[i]
        us_in[i] = tmp
  return us_in

print(ins_sort([5,2,4,6,1,3]))
```

Result:

```
[5,2,4,1,6,3]
```

Comment: After fixing the indentation I put a print statement in the second loop and it executed as expected (I've updated your question with fixed indentation). There is not an issue with your iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code right now. Mouse over the yellow if you can't figure it out ;)

One is in this piece of code:

```
for key in range(1, len(us_in)-1):
```

> You want to do `for key in range(1, len(us_in)):` so you reach every element of the list

And the other is in this block:

```
if us_in[key] < us_in[i] and key != 0:
    tmp = us_in[key]
    us_in[key] = us_in[i]
    us_in[i] = tmp
```

> When you're iterating, `key` is staying the same as you're going through. You want it to be moving WITH `i`, not just stay stationary. You can replace every occurrence of `i` with `i-1` and replace every `key` with `i` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Put "prints" everywhere, these will help you following the state of your variables.

That said, try putting the tmp variable outside the "if" statement.
And for running backwards, try this:

```
    for i in range(end):
        backwards = end - i
    #do something using "backwards" instead of "i"
```

Looks like you got your answer, anyway i won't delete this so you can keep the tip, as you're a begginer, print will be your best friend. trust me.

Comment: His method for running backwards works fine. I figured out what was wrong. See my answer if you're curious :)

Comment: you're right, tried your answer and it worked perfectly, still i'm courious about why his code woudln't work with an steady "key" variable.

Comment: If you think about it, if `key` stays the same, it will keep swapping `i` with `key` as `i` decreases, which is not what you want for insertion sort. With insertion sort, you can do 1 of two things. a) Swap the element down the list until you get to the end or b) Swap the element with the earliest place where it fits. OP looked like he's doing a), but he had a little bit of a challenge

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. I didn't realize that was happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 lines that you need to edit. 
3rd line it should be len (us_in) not len(us_in)-1
And in the if statement it should be 
    i  >= 0 
Instead of 
    Key !=0 
Also the second loop should start backward from key -1{ one less iteration}

Comment: This doesn't work, try running it. See my solution if you're confused on why OP's code doesn't work :)

Comment: yes i agree this doesn't work. your solution is correct.